# Advanced string literal support in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

In layouts (XML) on Android you may initiate some UI components with text values using the attribute `android:text`. As far as I know, you may only pass either hard-coded literals or simple strings without arguments (i.e. `R.string.xxx`).

I was wondering about the two following cases:

**Case 1: Strings with argument placeholders**

Example:

```
<string name="restart">Restart %1$s</string>
```

**Case 2: Plurals**

Example:

```
<plurals name="years">
    <item quantity="one">%1$s year</item>
    <item quantity="other">%1$s years</item>
</plurals>
```

As far as I know I need to programmatically (in the fragment/activity that inflates the layout) set the android:text attribute using these strings. This isn't very clean in my opinion.

**Question:** Is there a way to set these strings properly (with arguments) directly in XML?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because of `string.xml` resources are added to `R.java`, and `R.java` is an auto generated file contains all your resources used in the project. and if you want to change `strings.xml` at runtime you can't.

This is a basic thing in Android. You have to read Android Developers documents, then you will get good knowledge about it.